# DataModel and DataModelSelection in Seam3

Tags: seam, seam2, seam3

I cannot seem to find where is @DataModel and @DataModelSelection in Seam3 (as opposed to Seam2). In what Seam module are they defined? If their name has been changed, what is it currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using JSF2.0, you can 'inject' selection to action methods like this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{itemManager.itemList}" var="item">
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Item Id</f:facet>
      #{item.id}
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Item Name</f:facet>
      #{item.name}
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
      <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{itemManager.delete(item)}" />
   </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

and corresponding managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="itemManager")
@SessionScoped
public class ItemManager {
    ArrayList<Item> itemList;

    public ArrayList<Item> getItemList() {
        if (itemList == null) {
            itemList = ... // build item list
        }
        return itemList;
    }

    public String delete(Item item) {
        itemList.remove(item);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Method parameters are allowed in JSF2 EL without the JBoss extension.

Answer (score 2):

@DataModel and @DataModelSelection feature is not available in Seam3.

Comment: Do you happen to know is there a corresponding feature in Seam3? What kind of alternative have people used when migrated? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I you use richfaces, you can use the following construct:

```
<a:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{bean.delete}">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{bean.selectedItem}" />
</a:commandLink>
```